# Can I declare a simple function in an angular template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have a component that will bind a function from the "page" controller.

```
<my-component fn=""></my-component>
```

My component will then execute that function. My question is this: can I create a simple anonymous function in the view to pass in? Something like this:

```
<my-component fn="(obj)=>obj.name"></my-component>
```

or

```
<my-component fn="function(obj){return obj.name;}"></my-component>
```

Those syntaxes don't work, but I wanted to know if something like that can be done. I can't find an example of it, but I feel like it should be possible.

Comment: perhaps you want to use a filter instead? this won't work

Comment: @DanielA.White I have other ways of going about it, I was just curious if I _could_ do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done. And it certainly shouldn't be done. This pattern would look worse than `ng-init` (which itself isn't recommended). And this would create a huge hole in security.

Angular expression parser [takes care of special objects](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/ng/parse.js#L69-L94) to not let something like

```
ng-init="{{ fn = constructor.constructor('malicious code') }}"
```

Because *`eval` is evil*.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.